# Django Command: Load Data Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

Writing a django command that imports from a directory of `txt` files into a database. The database is created, however when run I get the lovely, indescript error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...path' at line 1")`. I have no clue to what to investigate. When I try a singular file into the mysql portal, it seems to work. How can I make the jump to a Django command?

Below is the command code:

```py
def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("\nStarting...")
        with connections['wk'].cursor() as cursor:
            db_name = settings.DATABASES['wk']['NAME']
            for path in glob.glob(f'{options["p"]}/*[!.sql]'):
                table_name = f'{db_name}.{path.rsplit("/")[-1].lower()}'
                cursor.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s", [path, table_name])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only let the connector do the substitution for data values, not for file names, table names, and field names.  What happens here is that you get double quoting.

So:

```
          cursor.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s" % (path, table_name))
```

Or

```
          cursor.execute(f"LOAD DATA INFILE '{path}' INTO TABLE {table_name}")
```